# How to create a folder on a SFTP server in Azure Logic Apps?

Tags: azure, sftp, azure-logic-apps

I verified the user has permission, but I do not see it showing up in the list of possible Logic Apps:

Here is a screenshot of what I can do and it is missing `Create Folder`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no create folder action available in the SFTP connector. Share your idea here
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps

Answer (score 1):

You can get around this problem by using the "SFTP Extract archive to folder". You need to put a file that contains a single zipped file on your SFTP server. Then use the connector just mentioned to unzip the zip file to the new folder you want to create. It will then create the required folder.

So I have a zip file called `CreateFolder.zip` which I unzip to a new folder. The SFTP server must have unzip installed, it won't work work with gunzip.

[image: Picture of connector]